how to save the whatsapp web.js session to mysql
I am currently attempting to persist session data to MySQL within an Express application. However, I am encountering difficulties finding an appropriate method to achieve this. If persisting session data directly to MySQL is not feasible, I am exploring alternatives such as returning the session data through Express and sending it to the client.
Here's the route I'm using to handle the /qr endpoint:
app.get('/qr', function (req, res) {
    res.send({qrs: qrm, status: stat, session: sessionData});
});

If it is possible to return the session data using Express, I would greatly appreciate an example or workaround to accomplish this. Thank you!
